# pass to third Activity Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Back with another question friends.
I have a ListView in which you charge different URL to send me to another activity that contains a webView and that this in turn display the URL. But within these options ListView is one that should behave differently , how do I move on to a third activity of the primary?

[Example in image](http://postimg.org/delete/q0ndo3w1o/)

Thanks for support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read about `onClickListener` for a listView ? Read about it here :  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

@Override  
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter,View v, int position){
     if(position == your_special_listview_position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this,thirdActivity.class);
        // Start Third Activity
        startActivity(intent);
      } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this,webViewActivity.class);
        // Start WEbview activity
        startActivity(intent);
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks helped me too and it was so simple T.T @Android2390